# Codeigniter - Date/Time when input is made to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've read numerous guides/pages etc on how CI escapes the NOW() function when using active records.

I've tried to utilise a function within a variable, and then call upon that within my array which inputs various fields into the database; but it doesn't appear to be working at all. The two methods I've tried are below, the second one is interpreted as 0000-00-00 in the database; the first one puts my AJAX controller into a loop, resulting in no data being added at all..

Thanks!

Attempt 1

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {
            // Passed the form validation

            **$initiated_date =  $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);**  

            $order = array(


                'status'          => $this->input->post('status'), 
                'priority'        => $this->input->post('priority'), 
                'target_date'     => $this->input->post('target_date'),
                'initiated_date'  => $this->input->post('$initiated_date'),
                'requestor_name'  => $this->input->post('requestor_name'),
                'requestor_telno' => $this->input->post('telephone'),           
                'job_description'        => $this->input->post('job_desc'), 
                'trade_type'    => $this->input->post('trade')

            );
```

Attempt 2

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
            {
                // Passed the form validation

                $initiated_date =  $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);  

                $order = array(


                    'status'          => $this->input->post('status'), 
                    'priority'        => $this->input->post('priority'), 
                    'target_date'     => $this->input->post('target_date'),
                    'initiated_date'  => $this->input->post('date', 'NOW()', FALSE), 
                    'requestor_name'  => $this->input->post('requestor_name'),
                    'requestor_telno' => $this->input->post('telephone'),           
                    'job_description'        => $this->input->post('job_desc'), 
                    'trade_type'    => $this->input->post('trade')

                );
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```
//sets variable and uses php date function
            $initiated_date =  date('Y-m-d');  

        $order = array(


            'status'          => $this->input->post('status'), 
            'priority'        => $this->input->post('priority'), 
            'target_date'     => $this->input->post('target_date'),
            'initiated_date'  => $initiated_date,
            'requestor_name'  => $this->input->post('requestor_name'),
            'requestor_telno' => $this->input->post('telephone'),           
            'job_description'        => $this->input->post('job_desc'), 
            'trade_type'    => $this->input->post('trade')

        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI input->post function is used to pull data from $_POST (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

'initiated_date' => $initiated_date

If you want to set initiated_date as the timestamp, you can use the php time() function:  $initiated_date = time()

Comment: thanks for your help on this one, I managed to fix where I was going wrong with your direction.